# MySQL Workbench: Unable to Connect to Table

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, mysql-workbench

I am working on a MySQL database having around 12 tables and it is on remote server. The connection is established via SSH. I have setup the client with MySQL Workbench and SqlYog. The connections are setup properly and database operations are getting performed well, except for one table. Whenever I am trying to access that table in workbench by directly clicking on the icon or by writing query, it is saying-

```
Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server at 
'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060
```

But the same table can be accessed from SqlYog. This is something become really messy. How can this problem be sort out?

**Info:**

- MySQL v5.6
- MySQL Workbench v6.3.4

Comment: Potentially a bug of Workbench. Is there anything special about the table, such as table name, column name, etc?

Comment: There is nothing such special in table or column name which may cause conflict.

Comment: Hmm, would love to see that table on my server for debugging. Can you file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com, add your table definition and we will take a look. As a workaround for now, can you recreate the table with a different name?

Comment: @MikeLischke, I'll surely report that. Is there anything else required to add for supporting information, other than table definition?

Comment: Well, all the version info you can give of course (server, os, wb). Maybe also some additional observations (like that it works with SqlYog).

Comment: @MikeLischke, Please visit [Bug Report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78434) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on MAC/Linux then
check if MYSQL is UP by using following

```
ps ax | grep sql
```

if it is down, try to boot is manually, using following if its linux

```
service mysql restart
```

if its mac and you have macport installed, use following

```
sudo port load mysql56-server
```

Comment: mysqld service is already started. This is the problem with one particular table, not with entire database connection.